# Android: Is there just once instance of a HAL module?

Tags: android, shared-libraries, hal

I am confused about the lifetime and usage of HAL modules.  Traditionally, a HAL module is implemented as a set of hooks to various functions and is compiled into a shared library.  Suppose I have two applications that link to `libhardware` and both call `hw_get_module()` somewhere in their code.

```
struct my_audio_stream {
    struct audio_stream base;      /* base HAL */
    int count;
}

struct audio_module HAL_MODULE_INFO_SYM = {
    .base = 
        .common = {
           .tag = HARDWARE_MODULE_TAG,
           .module_api_version = AUDIO_MODULE_API_VERSION_0_1,
           .hal_api_version = HARDWARE_HAL_API_VERSION,
           .id = AUDIO_HARDWARE_MODULE_ID,
           .name = "USB audio HW HAL",
           .author = "The Android Open Source Project",
           .methods = &hal_module_methods,
        },
}
```

If I increment the count variable in one application, will it be visible to the other application?  I.e, is there just one global instance of the `my_audio_stream` module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hw_get_module()` eventually just calls a `dlopen()`

`dlopen()` will load library for the specific process that called it. Although .text (executable code) is shared between processes for a shared object, storages required by .so (e.g. for global/static objects) are allocated per process

So if two processes call `hw_get_module()` then globals declared in .so will not be shared between these processes.

It follows that count incremented in one process will not be seen by other process.

Having said that, Android will load only one instance of a HAL module, and use that forever internally. (There is only one instance of Audio Server)

If you need to access internals of your HAL from your app/process, you should implement some kind of IPC in your HAL.